# Getting an inner JSON value without knowing hash value

Tags: json, http, jsonp, getjson

When I make a Https GET call, the following JSON is returned

```
{"-KXprfmbpX6dEqXLU1z_":{"Pizzatype":"Margarita"},"Toppings":{"-KXprfm_PBdOYUYiWzkK":["Onions","Mushrooms"]}}
```

I want to retrieve the values of Pizzatype and Toppings. However I am not aware of the real time keys -KXprfmbpX6dEqXLU1z_ , -KXprfm_PBdOYUYiWzkK. I am coding in an online Bot building platform in Node. How can I retrieve these values?

Comment: do you know the order that they will come in? will `pizzatype` always be the first object and the first object in `toppings` will always be what you want?

Comment: @Minidodds This is not a good approach to using object literals because it relies on an assumption. Briillio AITeam, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @ Minidodds, No I do not know the order in which come. As they come, I will store them in real time database